# How can I catch an event when the computer resume from sleep/hibernate mode?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, windows-10, .net-4.5

I have a console application running on .net 4.5 (only).
I am trying to detect when the computer return from sleep/hibernate mode.
I tried using `Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged` but for some reason it doesn't work...
I am using ThinkPad laptop running windows 10, When I unplug the charging cable it does fire the event with the argument Mode = `PowerModes.StatusChange`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += new PowerModeChangedEventHandler(SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged);
        Console.WriteLine("This application is waiting for system events.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to terminate this application.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Enum.GetName(typeof(PowerModes), e.Mode));
        File.WriteAllText("test.txt", "test");
    }
}
```

Tried printing to the screen and writing to a file, couldn't managed to make it work...

Please if someone have an idea or a different approach, in the end I need to catch when the computer returns from sleep or hibernate.

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0): "*This event is only raised if the message pump is running.*" Your code does not have a message loop that is pumping and dispatching messages.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well I am not using a `Windows Service`, I am using `Console App`. The message pump suppose to be running, the event is being raised when I unplug/plug the power cable, soo it seems to work there...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SOLVED:

From windows 10, microsoft added [Modern Standby](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby) that expands the Windows 8.1 Connected Standby power model.
`SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged` in .net 4.5 only supports Traditional Sleep and Hibernate (S1-4).

From windows 10, version 2004 Modern Standby is forced and cannot be disabled, renders `SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged` useless in my case.

The new Win32 API for handling Modern Standby power mode changes is referenced here:
[PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification function MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/powerbase/nf-powerbase-powerregistersuspendresumenotification)

Unfortunately I didn't managed to find a complete C# implementation for the new API.

Soo I made one myself using C# wrappers for `User32.dll` and `PowrPorf.dll` from [Vanara Project By dahall (GitHub)](https://github.com/dahall/Vanara):

```
public static class SystemPowerNotifications
    {
        public static event SystemPowerNotificationEventHandler PowerModeChanged 
        { 
            add
            {                           
                _powerModeChanged += value;
                if (_eventHandler == null)
                {
                    var result = PowrProf.PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification(PowrProf.RegisterSuspendResumeNotificationFlags.DEVICE_NOTIFY_CALLBACK,
                    _dnsp, out _eventHandler);
                    if (result != Win32Error.ERROR_SUCCESS)
                        throw new Exception();
                }
            } 
            remove 
            {
                _powerModeChanged -= value;
                if(_powerModeChanged.GetInvocationList().Length == 0)
                {
                    if (PowrProf.PowerUnregisterSuspendResumeNotification(_eventHandler) != Win32Error.NO_ERROR)
                        throw new Exception();
                    _eventHandler.Dispose();
                    _eventHandler = null;
                }       
            }
        }

        private static PowrProf.SafeHPOWERNOTIFY _eventHandler;
        private static PowrProf.DEVICE_NOTIFY_SUBSCRIBE_PARAMETERS _dnsp = new PowrProf.DEVICE_NOTIFY_SUBSCRIBE_PARAMETERS
        {
            Callback = OnDeviceNotify,
            Context = IntPtr.Zero
        };
        private static Win32Error OnDeviceNotify(IntPtr context, uint type, IntPtr setting)
        {
            _powerModeChanged?.Invoke(null,new PowerNotificationArgs((PowerBroadcastType)type));
            return 0;
        }
        private static SystemPowerNotificationEventHandler _powerModeChanged;
    }
```

Full source code:
[SystemPowerModeNotification-dotnet4.5 (GitHub)](https://github.com/Ethan-S-Dev/SystemPowerModeNotification-dotnet4.5)

EDIT:

When using it inside a Windows Service, the callback function registered in `PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification` will fire only when going to Hibernate mode, and not in Modern Standby Sleep/Monitor Off.

There for you need to register to a different notification called `RegisterPowerSettingNotification` referenced here: [Registering for Power Events MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/registering-for-power-events)
and when a `PowerEvent` check the monitor state.
Take in mind that it will happen even if the computer will enter Monitor Off/On state without entering sleep mode.

Example of registration:

```
public static event SystemPowerNotificationEventHandler PowerModeChanged
        {
            add
            {
                _powerModeChanged += value;
                if (_powerEventHandler == null)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ServiceName))
                    {
                        if (_ssh.IsNull)
                            _ssh = AdvApi32.RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(ServiceName, OnDisplayNotify);
                        if (_ssh.IsNull)
                            throw new Exception("Failed To Register ServiceCtrlHandlerEx");
                        _displayEventHandler = User32.RegisterPowerSettingNotification(((IntPtr)_ssh), PowrProf.GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON, User32.DEVICE_NOTIFY.DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE);
                        if (_displayEventHandler.IsNull)
                            throw new Exception("Failed To Register PowerSettingNotification");
                    }

                    var result = PowrProf.PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification(PowrProf.RegisterSuspendResumeNotificationFlags.DEVICE_NOTIFY_CALLBACK,
                    _dnsp, out _powerEventHandler);
                    if (result != Win32Error.ERROR_SUCCESS)
                        throw new Exception("Failed To Register PowerSuspendResumeNotification");
                }

            }
            remove
            {
                _powerModeChanged -= value;
                if (_powerModeChanged == null)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ServiceName))
                    {
                        if (!User32.UnregisterPowerSettingNotification(_displayEventHandler))
                            throw new Exception("Failed To Unregister PowerSettingNotification");
                        _displayEventHandler.Dispose();
                        _displayEventHandler = null;
                    }

                    if (PowrProf.PowerUnregisterSuspendResumeNotification(_powerEventHandler) != Win32Error.NO_ERROR)
                        throw new Exception("Failed To Unregister PowerSuspendResumeNotification");
                    _powerEventHandler.Dispose();
                    _powerEventHandler = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Example of the callback:

```
private static Win32Error OnDisplayNotify(AdvApi32.ServiceControl control,uint eventType,IntPtr eventData,IntPtr context)
        {
            var dataHandle = new HANDLE(eventData);
            var contextHandle = new HANDLE(context);
            if(control == AdvApi32.ServiceControl.SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT)
            {
                POWERBRODCAST_SETTING settings = (POWERBRODCAST_SETTING)Marshal.PtrToStructure(eventData, typeof(POWERBRODCAST_SETTING));
                _powerModeChanged?.Invoke(null, new PowerNotificationArgs((PowerBroadcastType)eventType,settings.Data));
            }
            
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: There could be only one handler registered via RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx, therefore after you register custom handler it overrides handler in ServiceBase and the original handler won't ever be called. As a result the service is impossible to stop/restart or send any other command